# Inferring the missing verbs from「世の中に知らしめるんだ 僕の存在を正義の裁きを下す者が いるってことを」

Tags: meaning, translation, context

Here's a transcript segment from the first episode of Death Note, where the main character goes on an egotistical rant:

> 18:03
>
> 世の中に知らしめるんだ 僕の存在を
>
> 18:06
>
> 正義の裁きを下す者が いるってことを

The speaker then gets interrupted

> 18:11
>
> いや しかし 正義の裁きを下して どうするつもりだ？

The speaker seems to end sentences with を (leaving the verb to be inferred by the listener). So I'm trying to peace together what the full sentence(s) would be. Is it something like this?

1. 世の中に知らしめるんだ ("I will make it known to the world"; complete as is)
2. 僕の存在を**知らしめる** ("I will make my existence known to the world"; 知らしめる inferred)
3. 正義の裁きを下す者がいるってことを**知らしめる** ("I will make it known that there is someone who passes down justice's judgment"; "知らしめる inferred again)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a typical example of 倒置文 ([anastrophe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anastrophe)), where the object comes after the corresponding verb. You don't have to "infer" the verb; the verb (知らしめる "to make someone know") is explicitly there, albeit in an unusual place. And there are two objects marked with を in parallel.

Here is the full sentence in the ordinary word order:

> 世の中に僕の存在**を**、(そして)正義の裁きを下す者がいるってこと**を**知らしめるんだ。
>
> I will make the world aware of my existence and that there is someone to mete out justice.